# Vue-cal error when importing in component

Tags: vue.js, vue-cal

After install `npm i vue-cal`

and in my js file:

`import VueCal from 'vue-cal'`

I get this message in the console:
`Failed to resolve module specifier "vue-cal"`

Comment: You should probably import the component inside a Vue file rather than a JS file?

Comment: I'm using options api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to the Doc, Vue Cal is a component so you have to use it like a component.

You have to do something like that:

```js
import VueCal from 'vue-cal'
import 'vue-cal/dist/vuecal.css'

export default {
  components: { VueCal },
  ...
}
```

Documentation https://antoniandre.github.io/vue-cal/

**Still got error?**

You can remove the import above and use a script, in the documentation above related to the section *Or via  tag*.

In your file index.html inside the head tag:

```html
<head>
  ...
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@legacy"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-cal@legacy"></script>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/vue-cal@legacy/dist/vuecal.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Now Vue cal is available overall in your vue app, you just have to go in your component and do that:

```js
export default {
  components: { VueCal: vuecal },
}
```

Comment: Yes, I used it as in the documentation, still got the error.

Comment: Not sur about the problem but you can avoid it with the script, i update my comment.

Comment: With the script I got it running.... Thanx